# Where is the source of the following text inside the documentation?

Tags: magento2, documentation

On the DevDocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html  Link, there is the following text bellow the mixin example:

```
@font-display: swap is declared by default for Magento Blank theme in app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_typography.less.
Fallback web fonts that are used by default in Magento are located in lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less.
```

In the DevDeocs  .md file of that URL, that text is missing…?!
See attached screenshots.

1)Where is that text’s source?

2)How does it getting displayed there, when there is nothing in the md file. 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the github page it seems to appear -

https://github.com/magento/devdocs/blob/master/src/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.md

So perhaps there was a commit that updated it with this?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and yes i see it on the link now. 
but i still cant find the same file in the my local clone of the devdocs repository. 
Specially the path devdocs/blob/master/src/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.md  doesn't exist in the git repo i have locally. 
Where do i get to edit that file?
Thank you!